# How do I speed up a large website category navigation?

Tags: php, laravel, web, menu

I have a category menu on a website that goes about four levels deep. There are a few thousand links included. My current implementation simply loops through each level to add top-level items and then any child items. This appears to cause quite a big slowdown to the site (even with caching). I did try a recursive approach but if anything that seemed slower still.

I'm thinking there must be a faster way of doing this as there are plenty of sites out there with similar set-ups that are nowhere near as slow.

My current code looks like:

```
$menu = Cache::remember('menu', 60*60, function() {
            $toplevelCategories = Category::select('id', 'name', 'position', 'enabled')->where('path', '')->orWhereNull('path')->where('menu', 1)->where('enabled', 1)->get();
        
            $menu = (new FrontendMenu());
    
            foreach ($toplevelCategories as $category) {
                $menuItem = new FrontendItem(null, $category->name, $category->getUrl(), $category->enabled, $category->position);
    
                $allSubCategories = Category::select('id', 'name', 'path', 'position', 'enabled')
                                                ->whereIn('path', [$category->id])
                                                ->where('menu', 1)
                                                ->where('enabled', 1)
                                                ->get();
                
                $secondLevelCategories = $allSubCategories->filter(function($val) {
                    if (count(explode('/', $val->path)) == 1) {
                        return $val;
                    }
                });
    
                foreach ($secondLevelCategories as $categoryChild) {
                    $secondaryMenuItems = new FrontendItem($menuItem, $categoryChild->name, $categoryChild->getUrl(), $categoryChild->enabled, $categoryChild->position);
    
                    $thirdLevelCategories = $allSubCategories->filter(function($val) use ($categoryChild) {
                        if (count(explode('/', $val->path)) == 2 && str_contains($val->path, $categoryChild->id)) {
                            return $val->path;
                        }
                    });
    
                    foreach ($thirdLevelCategories as $categoryChild) {
                        new FrontendItem($secondaryMenuItems, $categoryChild->name, $categoryChild->getUrl(), $categoryChild->enabled, $categoryChild->position);
                    }
                }
                
                $menu->addItem($menuItem);
            }

            return $menu;    
        });
```

This works and achieves the desired result however it is extremely slow. I did also try a recursive approach just with a function that would call itself and build the menu but that seemed slower if anything.

Comment: You might want to rethink the way that you're storing your categories - depending on how often they change, a nested set might be more efficient.

Comment: Your issue seems to be that you are running queries inside loops. You should try to optimize that, get subcategories in bulk using a single query and filter them inside your loop. You can install tools like [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) or [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) to identify exactly which queries are slowing down your application.